# Unable to start test using mstest remotely with powershell

Tags: powershell, mstest, remote-access

I have a problem with running **mstest.exe remotely** using **powershell**. I need it to run automated tests on other machine.
I try to do the next command:

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName remoteComputer" -ScriptBlock { & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" "/testcontainer:myTests.dll"}
```

And after that I get the next error:
**Failed to queue test run 'username@machinename 2017-10-03 13:30:18': Unable to start the agent process.**
So I see that mstest was started and tests were loaded but it can't start agnet process.
I tried to specify credentials but the same. Though I'm admin on both machines and run powershell as administrator.
When I run the same command on the remote machine locally in cmd then mstest works correctly.
Did anyone has the similar issue?

Comment: I am having similar issue. How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: any luck with this issue?

Comment: Have you checked that the .NET that is being used is up to date?

Comment: Have you logged into the remote computer with the user being used to run the remote command? I've seen where remote commands don't create a proper user profile, and programs expect to run in a proper user profile.

Comment: @Neoxidine its up to date

Comment: @VertigoRay - Yes ive logged in with the user being used to run the remote command - the profile is proper and the batch file is working fine when being executed directly in the remote system but not working if i try to execute the batch from my system using a powershell.

Comment: Does `mstest.exe` run interactively?  With a GUI?

Comment: @Anu7 can you please refer to the following link if this is what you are looking for? https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsProtocolTestSuites/wiki/Remotely-Trigger-Test-Suites

Comment: I think you may need to put the full path and filename to your `myTests.dll` in parameter `/testcontainer:`. The current paths on your machine may differ from the remote machine.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 yes, it does without any issues at all

Comment: @Theo yes, I've done that as well.. that isn't working either

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running something like:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer remote -ScriptBlock {Start-Process <mstest details>...}
```

The Invoke-Command should get you the remote access, the Start-Process should run the mstest

Comment: using this but it doesnt work:: Invoke-Command -ComputerName $systemName -credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-Expression -Command: "cmd.exe /c 'C:\temp\01_Start.bat'" }

Comment: while Invoke-expression is yeilding some result, using start-process isn't working for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about how mstest works.

Try to create a schedule task in the remote computer with all you need and in your Script Block just call this task

I'm sure this is not the best way, but try to do this.

The task will run locally and I think the mstest will run without any problem.

Comment: this was the solution I was going to if i dont find the primary requirement ( to run a batch on remote from a powershell on my system) Thank you for the answer though !!

Answer (score 0):

When you run mstest.exe remotely using powershell you need to add "/noisolation" property to the command in the script block:

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName remoteComputer" -ScriptBlock { & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" "/testcontainer:myTests.dll" "/noisolation" }
```